# How to remove more than one space when reading text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Problem: I cannot seem to parse the information in a text file because python reads it as a full string not individual separate strings. The spaces between each variable is not a \t which is why it does not separate. Is there a way for python to flexibly remove the spaces and put a comma or \t instead?

Example DATA:

```
MOR125-1   MOR129-1   0.587
MOR125-1   MOR129-3   0.598
MOR129-1   MOR129-3   0.115
```

The code I am using:

```
with open("Distance_Data_No_Bootstrap_RAW.txt","rb") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
d=list(reader)
for i in range(3):
    print d[i]
```

Output:

`['MOR125-1   MOR129-1   0.587']
['MOR125-1   MOR129-3   0.598']
['MOR129-1   MOR129-3   0.115']`

Desired Output:

```
['MOR125-1', 'MOR129-1', '0.587']
['MOR125-1', 'MOR129-3', '0.598']
['MOR129-1', 'MOR129-3', '0.115']
```

Comment: Change delimiter to space, and get rid of any extra spaces by using .strip() string method

Comment: If I change the delimiter to space, all single spaces that exist in the string turn into commas. At that point it is a list with strings and spaces separated by commas. I'm not sure how I would perform an .strip() to remove the spaces if it isn't a complete list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply declare the delimiter to be a space, and ask csv to skip initial spaces after a delimiter. That way, your separator is in fact the regular expression `' +'`, that is one or more spaces.

```
rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
for row in rd:
    print row
```

```
['MOR125-1', 'MOR129-1', '0.587']
['MOR125-1', 'MOR129-3', '0.598']
['MOR129-1', 'MOR129-3', '0.115']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can instruct [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to use space as delimiter and skip all the extra space:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
```

For detailed information about available parameters check [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters):

> Dialect.delimiter
>   A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.
>   Dialect.skipinitialspace
>   When True, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored. The default is False.